# Is "an independent clause" the same as "a sentence?"

Tags: grammar-myths

Knowing that the clause is a group of words that contain mainly a subject and a tense , and it may be dependent or **independent**, what is the difference between the latter and **a sentence.**?  This doubt is due to the fact that the author of a textbook, uses "a sentence" in the middle of explanations related to connectors after having been using "clauses" all the time, so I am in doubt whether he is referring to the same but with a different name.

Comment: Your first sentence contains two independent clauses (*and it may be dependent or independent* and *what is the difference between the latter and a sentence?*). Either independent clause may stand on its own as a sentence. For example, the following is a sentence: *What is the difference between the latter and a sentence?* And the following is a sentence: *And it may be dependent or independent.* But you have not used either as a sentence  but as an independent clause in a sentence that contains three clauses.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize AlanCarmack's explanation, an independent clause is a complete sentence joined to another clause or clauses, which themselves may be either dependent or independent.

Independent clauses, or *coordinate clauses*, are joined by *coordinating conjunctions*, which are *and, but, or, for, nor, yet,* and *so*.  Dependent clauses, or *subordinate clauses*, are joined by *subordinating conjunctions*, some of which are *after, although, as, because, before, how, if, since, though, until, when, where,* and *while*.  Clauses that begin with these can't function as sentences on their own; they have to be joined to another clause that can function as a sentence on its own.

Here's an example of each:

> I went to the ball game yesterday, and I saw my friend Tim there.
>   I went to the ball game yesterday, where I saw my friend Tim.

Now, have a look at this:

> I went to the ball game yesterday.  I saw my friend Tim there.
>   I went to the ball game yesterday.  Where I saw my friend Tim.

Of these sentences, "Where I saw my friend Tim." is incorrect, because it isn't a complete sentence.  All the other sentences are correct.